# Socket API - Server code seems to work but client is not receiving

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi, pynput

Trying to send data from Raspberry Pi to Windows PC. I wired a joystick to the pi and the program outputs W A S D etc. that is supposed to be sent over to PC, then PC will press corresponding key. Right now, the output of server is outputting the correct W A S D keys, while the client is not outputting anything. Here is the code for the server on the Pi:

```
import socket
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import ADC0834
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

BtnPin = 22
bufferSize = 1024
ServerPort = 2000
ServerIP = "192.123.1.456"

# Make socket
RPIsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind socket
RPIsocket.bind((ServerIP, ServerPort))

# GPIO pin set up 
def setup():
    # Set the GPIO modes to BCM Numbering
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(BtnPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    ADC0834.setup()
    
# Release resource
def destroy():
    GPIO.cleanup() 

# Read joystick input then send command to client
def loop():
    while True:
        x_val = ADC0834.getResult(0)
        y_val = ADC0834.getResult(1)
        Btn_val = GPIO.input(BtnPin)
        
    # Map joystick input to keyboard keys
        if y_val < 117: # Middle is 127
            key_name = 'w'
        elif y_val > 137: # Middle is 127
            key_name = 's'
        else:
            key_name = None
            
        if x_val < 121: # Middle is 131
            key_name = 'a'
        elif x_val > 141: # Middle is 131
            key_name = 'd'
            
        if key_name:
            cmd = key_name.encode('utf-8')
            RPIsocket.sendto(cmd, (ServerIP,ServerPort))
            print("Sending command:", cmd)
        
        if Btn_val == 0:
            cmd = 'f'.encode('utf-8')
            RPIsocket.sendto(cmd, (ServerIP,ServerPort))
            print("Sending command:", cmd)
            
        time.sleep(0.2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
    try:
        loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt: # Press Ctrl C to end program
        destroy()
```

and here is the client side's code:

```
import socket
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

bufferSize = 1024
ServerPort = 2000
ServerIP = "192.123.1.456"
PCsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
PCsocket.bind((ServerIP, ServerPort))

def send_key(key):
    if key == 'w':
        keyboard.press('w')
        keyboard.release('w')
    elif key == 'a':
        keyboard.press('a')
        keyboard.release('a')
    elif key == 's':
        keyboard.press('s')
        keyboard.release('s')
    elif key == 'd':
        keyboard.press('d')
        keyboard.release('d')
    elif key == 'f':
        keyboard.press('f')
        keyboard.release('f')

def main():
    while True:
        data, addr = PCsocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
        cmd = data.decode('utf-8')
        print("Received command:", cmd)
        send_key(cmd)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run and debug, this is the error it's outputting: `OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context`

Comment: On the RPI, is the `ServerIP` the RPI IP?  The sender does not need to bind, and should `.sendto()` the receiver IP/port.  The receiver binds to a local port (`.bind('', port)` will do) so it will receive anything sent to the receiver's IP/port via `.recvfrom()`.  It can reply to the sender via the `addr` received from `.recvfrom()` if desired.